# Non-english Section numbering problem

Tags: xetex, number, renewcommand

I have the following code for numbering the section numbers in Bengali language.

```
\makeatletter
\def\bengalidigits#1{\expandafter\@bengali@digits #1@}
\def\@bengali@digits#1{%
  \ifx @#1
  \else
    \ifx0#1০\else\ifx1#1১\else\ifx2#1২\else\ifx3#1৩\else\ifx4#1৪\else\ifx5#1৫\else\ifx6#1৬\else\ifx7#1৭\else\ifx8#1৮\else\ifx9#1৯\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \expandafter\@bengali@digits
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\def\bengalinumber#1{\bengalidigits{\number#1}}
\def\bengalinumeral#1{\bengalinumber{\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\renewcommand\thesection{\bengalinumeral{section}}
```

However, this makes only the section numbers Bengali. It does not translate the subsection or the subsubsections. Please see the image below for a clear understanding.

[image]

As you can see, only the section numbers changed. But the subsection and subsubsection numbers are still in English. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot really reproduce this, based on the fact that your code is not a complete minimal working example, and apparently my computer does not want to output bengali numerals, BUT I did see in your code that you only re-define `\thesection` to use the numbers you define, have you tried `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\bengalinumeral{subsection}}`?

Answer (score 1):

Like [@MarkusG. already suggested in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600020/non-english-section-numbering-problem#comment1504972_600020) you have to also change the definition of `\thesubsection` to alter subsection numbering.

This answer also contains an, imho, better definition of the Bengali counter formatting (I called it `\bengalinum`), that uses `\ifcase` to select the correct digit instead of a deeply nested `\ifx` structure. Also, the check for the end of the number is faster by utilizing TeX's delimited argument grabbing rules instead of using an `\ifx` test for that as well.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@gobbletorelax#1\relax{}
\newcommand\bengalinum[1]{\expandafter\@bengalinum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\@bengalinum[1]{\expandafter\@bengalinum@\the#1\relax}
\newcommand\@bengalinum@[1]
  {%
    \@gobbletorelax#1\@bengalinum@end\relax
    \@bengalinum@digit{#1}%
  }
\newcommand\@bengalinum@digit[1]
  {%
    \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`0\relax
      ০\or % 0
      ১\or % 1
      ২\or % 2
      ৩\or % 3
      ৪\or % 4
      ৫\or % 5
      ৬\or % 6
      ৭\or % 7
      ৮\or % 8
      ৯\else % 9
      -\fi % not a digit, must be a sign
    \@bengalinum@
  }
\def\@bengalinum@end#1\@bengalinum@digit#2{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\thesection{\bengalinum{section}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\bengalinum{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

(no output shown here, as I have no idea which font to use for this to work)

Comment: There is a disadvantage in the `\ifcase` method in that negative and non-integer numbers (ie, with the minus sign or a decimal mark) fail, because the argument must be a number. IMO, the `\ifx` method is more general, robust and scalable in this regard, although the definition in the OP should be improved slightly.

Comment: @JavierBezos that's a non-problem in section numbering :)

Comment: Sure . I just liked to point out it's not the most general solution.

Comment: @JavierBezos also, a decimal mark can't be part of an integer... :) Afterall this is a macro like `\arabic`, or `\roman`, that just prints a count register in a formatted way. But I altered the macro to be able to print a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the lenghty `\ifx` chain, I propose `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Kohinoor Bangla}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bengalinum}{m}
 {
  \israt_bengalinum:e { \int_to_arabic:n { \value{#1} } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \israt_bengalinum:n
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__israt_bengalinum_digit:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \israt_bengalinum:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \__israt_bengalinum_digit:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {0}{০}
    {1}{১}
    {2}{২}
    {3}{৩}
    {4}{৪}
    {5}{৫}
    {6}{৬}
    {7}{৭}
    {8}{৮}
    {9}{৯}
   }
   {#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\bengalinum{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\bengalinum{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\bengalinum{page}}

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\bengalinum{test}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Test 1}

\subsection{Test 2}

\setcounter{test}{-3}$\thetest$

\setcounter{test}{1234567890}\thetest

\section{Another}

\subsection{Test 1}

\subsection{Test 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The value of the counter is converted to Arabic digits; then we map the result one digit (or possible minus sign) at a time with a direct translation into the Bengali digit.